# Remove/Hide div From Website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a css animation that essentially slides two images with a high z-index off the screen revealing the website content below it on the home page. It is only on the home page and not on any other pages.

What I would like to do is have this animation run only the first time the page is accessed during a session. So if the user navigates to another page and then comes back to the home page, I don’t want the animation to run again.

The only solution I can think of is to create an HTML5 session storage object on the first page load that is checked every time the home page is loaded and use jquery to hide div that contains animation if the value of the object is set.

This seems a bit overkill for such a simple task. Any suggestions on a simpler way of just removing the div that is persistent across page reloads during the session? You don’t have to write the code for me, just point me in a simpler direction if possible. Like is there a way to do this with just CSS. Or if I remove the element using JavaScript will it remain removed after navigating to another page within site and then coming back to home page. Please and thanks!

P.S. This is a custom WordPress theme so I’m open to a PHP solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Client-side session storage was what I was thinking to do. Just wanted to know if their was any other solution I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the referrer URL and run the animation only if the referrer is not the site itself. But this time the animation won't be shown if the visitor first opens another page and then navigates to the homepage.

Another option would be using cookies.

Comment: This seems like a better solution than what I had in mind. Thanks. I will try.